# how does randint() evaluate in an if, and else statement?

Tags: python

I just started teaching myself programming a few days ago and I had a simple question as to why the following code block works the way it does.

I searched for quite a bit of time here and on google, but have had issues finding a specific answer.  So I thought i'd break the ice here at SO and ask real people who can understand my question.

```
    if randint(0,1):
        print ("Choice 1")
    else:
        if randint(0,1):
            print("Choice 2")
```

When I run this, it works as I need it to,  but the question I have is, "Why does it work?"

So in my mind I see a random number (0 or 1) being generated.   Since there's only two possible numbers,  does it evaluate into a true/false statement?  like 0 is true, and 1 is false?    I'm not trying to use this for any program,  it's just an example I made up to illustrate my question.

Thanks for reading,  and I apologize if I posted here incorrectly.  I plan on using this awesome site quite a bit and don't want to get started on the wrong foot.

edit:  Thanks everyone for replying so quickly,  I wish I could give the 'answer' to everyone that replied.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: Notice that as written, this will still only print something 25% of the time because a new random number is generated for every randint() call. If you want to reference the same random number twice, you must save it to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 evaluates to False, nonzero evaluates to True.

```
if 0:
    print 'a'
elif 1:
    print 'b'

# prints 'b'
```

Your code has a 50% chance of outputting Choice 1, a 25% chance of outputting Choice 2, and a 25% chance of outputting nothing.

Comment: See here for details https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: Ahhhhh thank you Chris.  I get it now.   I didn't even realize that the else statement could end in no output,  but now I see it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) in Python. Each call to `randint` produces either 1 or 0, and 0's booleanness is False. Note that in your example, 25% of the time neither condition will be met. What you might be attempting to do is something like this:

```
num = randint(0,1)
if num: 
  do something
else:
  do something else
```

Duck typing can be used in lots of other situations too. For example, empty lists, dictionaries, and sets all evaluate to false, so instead of using `while len(my_list)>0` you can just use `while my_list`. None also evaluates to False, so you can do things like `if re.match(pattern, string)` instead of `if re.match(pattern, string) != None`.

A good rule of thumb is just to assume that things will work the way you think they will. Python's duck typing is pretty robust.

Comment: man, that's awesome stuff.  I should have asked all you guys sooner.  Thanks for the indepth reply, whereswalden.

Comment: No problem! Duck typing is one of the reasons people like Python. If you like this answer (or any other on SO), you can show your gratitude by upvoting it.

Comment: I definitely will once I get permission.

Answer (score 0):

if statements not only check types, but for truthy and falsy statements as well. `0` for example, is falsy. so `if 0` would trigger the else statement.

So, your code says: if a random number is 1, print Choice 1. If a random number is 0, the else triggers and once again asks if a random number is 1 to print choice 2

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it automatically evaluate them as boolean. This is a common behaviour of many programming languages. Actually 0 evaluates to False and 1 evaluates to True.